# Unsafe State and Safe State

Tags: operating-system, thread-safety, system, unsafe, bankers-algorithm

I have learned a little about Unsafe State and Safe State.

Safe State is when there is no chance of deadlock occuring, while unsafe state doesn't mean a deadlock has occurred yet, but means that a deadlock could happen.

What I'm trying to figure out is if a system is in an UNSAFE state, can it ever return to a safe state?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think the answer depends on how it got in the UNSAFE state. Without some intervention to change the conditions that led it to an unsafe state, it probably won't be able to recover. The UNSAFE state is often the result of some programming-logic error.

Comment: Please find my response here: [http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-unsafe-state-not-always-cause-deadlock/63942#63942](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-unsafe-state-not-always-cause-deadlock/63942#63942)

Comment: Please find the response in following thread: [answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-unsafe-state-not-always-cause-deadlock/63942#63942)

Answer (score 0):

Off course it can be figured out to change it to safe state because the deadlock has not been occurred yet. it is deadlock avoidance mechanism that when you see that deadlock is going to occur in future then there is needed some mechanism to avoid deadlock from happening. so the possibility of occurring deadlock is AVOIDED.

Answer (score 0):

Safe state in OS is state in which all resources of system are **well managed**, All resources not assigned to one request,There shouldn't be **circular demand** of resources in your system. Simple is this that there shouldn't be dead lock. When system resources are distributed according to demanded resources there are enough free resources which can feed next process's resource demand